# How to perform Conversion of text to image and vice versa in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I am looking to convert an image to text which I intend to convert back to the image. I have looked into Base64 specified in the [link here.](http://myjeeva.com/convert-image-to-string-and-string-to-image-in-java.html) But the problem that I encounter is that Eclipse freezes every time I try to convert. In this case, the conversion of the text back to the image is where Eclipse seems to freeze. The code in Eclipse is shown below. Is it somewhere wrong? Or is there any other way to convert images to text and back to images?

```
                    try 
                        {            
                            File file3=new File(sfile2.toString());
                            // Reading a Image file from file system
                            FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file3);
                            byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file3.length()];
                            imageInFile.read(imageData);

                            // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
                            String imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);
                            System.out.println(imageDataString);
                            // Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array
                            byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(imageDataString);

                            // Write a image byte array into file system
                            FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(
                                    "water-drop-after-convert.jpg");

                            imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);

                            imageInFile.close();
                            imageOutFile.close();

                            System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e3) 
                        {
                        }                   
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't freezing when you `System.out.println`? How large is your image? Maybe you should do something with the exception, you are possible throwing an exception, but you don't realize it because of the empty catch block.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. It is because of the `System.out.println`. Out of curiosity, why does that happen? The size of the image is around 800 kb actually.